# Does starting a new game erase all event-only routes for the PokeWalker?

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver, pokemon-hgss-pokewalker

If I start a new HeartGold or SoulSilver game, will I lose all my downloaded event-only routes?

Answer (score 1):

If you reset your Pokéwalker, you will lose any Watts and steps, but keep your routes.

If you start a new save file, yes, you will lose all of your courses.

Source: [reply #5 and #6](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/960099-pokemon-heartgold-version/57314304)